# ConTeXt: Overlapping Frame Border Glitch

Tags: context, framed, border

I'm seeing some subtle glitches at two-and-three-line intersections where the unopposed line extends slightly beyond the intersection. See the image. Similar artifacts in Evince and Foxit. Since they occur at offsets less than 1pt, are they rounding errors? How do I get rid of them?

```
\setuplayout
    [ backspace=0.75in
    , width=7in
    ]

\starttext
\vbox{
    \rightskip 0pt plus 1fil
    \setupinterlinespace[off]
    \leavevmode
    \framed[height=1in,width=2in,rulethickness=1pt,frameoffset=0.5pt]{001}\hskip0pt
    \framed[height=1in,width=2in,rulethickness=1pt,frameoffset=0.5pt]{002}\hskip0pt
    \framed[height=1in,width=2in,rulethickness=1pt,frameoffset=0.5pt]{003}\hskip0pt
    \framed[height=1in,width=2in,rulethickness=1pt,frameoffset=0.5pt]{004}\hskip0pt
    \framed[height=1in,width=2in,rulethickness=1pt,frameoffset=0.5pt]{005}\hskip0pt
    \framed[height=1in,width=2in,rulethickness=1pt,frameoffset=0.5pt]{006}\hskip0pt
    \framed[height=1in,width=2in,rulethickness=1pt,frameoffset=0.5pt]{007}\hskip0pt
}
\stoptext
```

[image: glitch[1]]

Comment: In mupdf this glitch is scale-independent.  Therefore I say viewer issue.  Does it appear in print?

Comment: I'll test once I'm ready to print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The borders of `\framed` consists of four separate rules which overlap at the corners. The reason why it uses four separate rules is that you can disable the lines on each side with the `topframe`, `bottomframe` etc. keys.

In a PDF viewer this can lead to the effect that corners show visual artifacts where the rules overlap, but when you print the document the effect disappears.

```
\starttext

\startframed[width=6cm,height=6cm,rulethickness=5mm]
    %
\stopframed

\stoptext
```

[image]

When you don't need the feature to disable individual rules you can create a closed frame without overlapping corners with the `frame=closed` setting.

```
\starttext

\startframed[frame=closed,width=6cm,height=6cm,rulethickness=5mm]
    %
\stopframed

\stoptext
```

[image]